# What's the rest of Bill's incomplete sentence?

Tags: bill-and-ted

> Ted: I went into Cyrus Adler Music yesterday. He said he'd give me
> $6,400 for the Les Paul.
>
> **Bill: Are you saying...**
>
> Ted: Yeah.

What's the rest of Bill's incomplete sentence?

Movie name: *Bill & Ted Face the Music* (2020)

Comment: Are you saying [that you're giving up on the band]...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implication is that he's giving up on the band.

The reason is that he's thinking about taking the offer for his instrument (one of his most valued, both monetary and sentimental value). Without his instrument, he's no longer going to partake in making music.